# I want to adsense code right side js base embed player in blogger template

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, adsense, adsense-api

I have tried but the script code looks like

```
<script>// <![CDATA[  
$(function() {  
    if($("#bigframe").length>0){ 
        vartitle=$(".single-post-title").text();
        $("#titlevid").text(title);
        var bigvideo = $("#bigframe").attr("src");
        var videotag = '<iframe src="'+bigvideo+'"id="covervideo" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        $(videotag).appendTo("#myvideo");
        $("#bigframe").remove();    
    }    
    else {
        $("#myvideo").remove();    
    }  
});// ]]></script>
```

The website is here http://www.ytclips.in/2015/01/uttama-villain-kamal-haasan.html

I have adjusted that frame center to left using css in blogger

can anyone help me add adsense to right of that player

blogger template here..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvUiH6qnOlJUXdOaVp6VHpjRUE/edit

Answer (score 0):

You've got a script within a script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- responsive2 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7144942111468669"
     data-ad-slot="3183216109"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
//]]>
</script>
```

Edit this code to this:

```
<script>//<![CDATA[</script>
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- responsive2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7144942111468669"
         data-ad-slot="3183216109"
         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    //]]>
    </script>
```

That should display the ad.

Comment: That works anywhere fine, but i want insert right side of video that works with script mentioned on question.